# Node script with Typescript and ts-node: can't get to import anything, no matter the configuration and package type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm-scripts, ts-node

I have a React Typescript project that has multiple files that share a structure. The code is similar, but quite different between them at some points, and it's pretty common to have to copy-paste files and change bits of information to create some of those new files.

I wanted to create a Node script that, asking the user for some input, would do that automatically. As I don't want to create a package for this (as it's a simple script inside my current project), I just created a folder called `scripts` and put it there.

So, the project structure is as follows:

```
- node_modules/
- scripts/
  - myScript/
    - helpers/
    - index.ts
    - package.json
- ...
- src/
- tsconfig.json
- package.json
```

To be able to execute Typescript, I've installed the `ts-node` library, and I'm executing this script through an `npm script` in the main project's `package.json`:

`"run-script": "ts-node ./scripts/myScript"`

This project already has code inside its `src` folder, and this `scripts` folder is a complement that does not belong to the main application's code, and that's why I keep it separated in an external folder, as it acts more as a helping tool for developers in the team.

### The problem

Whenever I try to make an import, I get this error:

```
throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module ...
```

If I use dynamic imports for packages and set `esModuleInterop` in my `tsconfig` file, everything works fine. But as soon as I try to import a method with a relative path, it breaks:

```
const inquirer = (await import('inquirer')).default;
const fs = (await import('fs-extra')).default;
const { getCommonPath } = await import('./helpers/getCommonPath');
```

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module ...
```

I thought that could have to do with the directory path, but if I use `__dirname` in the import, it tells me it's not allowed because of the format of the path.

If I try to use non-dynamic imports in stead, I get the following error:

```
(node:106220) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

But if I do that, then I get this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for ...
```

Then I thought that would have to do with `ts-node` configuration, and I read to use ts-node-esm. But if I do that, then the first error appears again. I've also tried multiple configurations for `ts-node` (`esModuleInterop: true`, `esm: true`, `module: CommonJS|ES2020|ESNext`...) without luck.

### The question

What do I have to do to be able to write a **Node script with Typescript** that I can execute from a command line that **allows imports of both, external libraries and relative paths (that can be Typescript aswell)?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I've been able to make it work finally with normal imports. Steps I've followed. I've followed the documentation of [ts-node esm](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007):

- Install `ts-node` package.
- Create a `package.json` inside the `scripts` folder and set the `"type": "module"`.
- Add the following configuration to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "ESNext",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "esm": true // <--- this is the most important part
  },
  "compilerOptions": {...}
```

- Add the file extension (.ts) to your relative imports. Eslint-TS will complain, but it's the only way to make it work (otherwise it won't find the module):

```
import fs from 'fs-extra';
import { getSrcPath } from './helpers/getSrcPath.ts';
```

- Run your node script with `ts-node` in your `package.json`:

```
"run-my-script": "ts-node ./scripts/myScript"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the necessary dependencies by running the command **npm install typescript ts-node @types/node**.
2. Create a new **tsconfig.json** file in the **root** of your project with the following contents:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

This configuration file tells TypeScript how to compile your source code into JavaScript.

3. Create a new src directory in the root of your project and create your TypeScript files in this directory. For example, create a file called **main.ts**.
4. Write your TypeScript code in main.ts. You can use import statements to import external libraries and relative paths.
5. To run your script from the command line, you can use the ts-node command. For example, to run main.ts, you can use the command **ts-node src/main.ts**.

You can also add a script to your **package.json** file to make it easier to run your script. For example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/main.ts"
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try to follow your steps. The thing is that my main project already has configurations for Typescript and files in the `src` folder. This `scripts` folder is something different, that acts like a helper for the developers but it is embedded inside the main project. This means that I cannot "create a new src directory", since that already exists and has the application code in it. This script is different from the application code, and I would like to keep them separated (that's why I created a `scripts` folder).

Comment: The main project uses Typescript aswell, and I can make it work without issues with imports and so on. The problem comes with the script inside the `scripts` folder, that is acting completely different and only gives errors complaining about modules or wrong imports. That's what I'm having a hard time figuring out.